# How can i get a Lazy field in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

How can i get Lazy fields using Entity Manager?
Here is my code snippet

```
public class Internet implements Serializable{
      int id;
      // related fields 
      @ManyToOne (fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
      Browsers brow;
      //related public getters and setters.
 }
```

This is my Browser Hibernate class;

```
public class Browser implements Serializable{

  int id;
  String name;
  //and some other useful fields. 

  //here public getters and setters.
  public String getName(){
     return name; 
  }

  public void setName(String name){
     this.name = name
  }
  //and few more.
}
```

Now my requirement is that, i want the name of the browser when i get the instance of Browser using EntityManger's find method using Internet.id.

These two classes are in different packages. so i can't access browser.name directly. 
i want the name of the browser. when i debugged my program browser.name is getting null. is there any way to get the value of the browser.name using EntityManager.

I read few posts related to this question, but i didn't get any clue. Can any body helps to me.

> This is my code how i am using my pages and several things:

```
InternateObjectUsingPage usingPage = (InternateObjectUsingPage)pageWithName(InternateObjectUsingPage.class.getName());
    _em = EntityManager.createEntityManager();
    Internet ipReg = _em.find(Internet.class, _currentRow.getIpRegId()) ; // _currentRow.getInRegId() is id. 
    ipReg.getBrowser(); // recently i added as per the suggestion.
    if(ipReg != null){
        _refresh = true;
        usingPage.setInternet(ipReg);
        return usingPage;
    }
    _em.close();
```

that's how i am using my code, but i couldn't see any difference.

Comment: Thank SiB, i saw that, but i didn't pay more attention.

Comment: I annotate the field like in my Internet class Browsers as Lazy. when i check the value from **Internet object.Browser object. name**, i am getting correct value, but when i get the value with** getters** same object, i am getting another value. Is it any thing to do with lazy or my poor understanding in concept.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, in the method where you query for `Internet` object; call `internet.getBrowser()` to load it at that point itself.

```
Internet internet = 
  (Internet) query.getSingleResult(); // or the way you fetch via EM
internet.getBrowser();
```

or if you query for a list of objects:

```
List<Internet> internetList = 
  (List<Internet>) query.getSingleResult();  // or the way you fetch via EM
for(Internet internet: internetList){     
    internet.getBrowser();
}
```

I assume you have specified `FetchType.EAGER` as you don't want to load `Browser` every time you load `Internet`.

Comment: S you are right. i don't want to load Browser object every time. but i have a problem like, i am getting the Internet object in one page(one class) and i am passing that object to other class. there i am using this Internet  object. Actually i am using Aribaweb in that to select one property of browser(name) its expecting object, when i specify Internet object.Browser object.getName()(this is expecting object here), its saying unexpected expression. how can i select

Comment: You should be calling `internet.getBrowser()` at the very place where `internet` object is loaded from DB in a transaction otherwise only solution is to specify `FetchType.EAGER`.

Comment: The only options are Calling `internet.getBrowser()` at the time of loading `Internet` or re-query the DB for `Browser` using `em.find` with browserId.

Comment: i didn't understood this point clearly, how can i call **Internet.getBrowser()** when i want Internet object to pass other page. and how can i re-query can u explain to me please.

Comment: LAZY doesn't fetch related Object while loading the main object; if you specifically load the related object in the same transaction then `LazyInitializationException` wont be thrown if the loaded object is accessed. It doesn't matter that you are passing object to another page; wherever the internet object is built, call `getBrowser()` just to load the Browser.

Comment: I don't have any *transactions* i just opened one Entity manager connection and then i am getting the `Internet object` then sending that to other page, then i am closing this Entity managers object.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the EntityManager instance you're working with in the em variable, and the id of the Internet object to use in id, I assume at some point on your first page you are calling find like this:

```
Internet internet = em.find(Internet.class, id);
```

On **the very next line of code in the same method** do this:

```
internet.getBrowser();
```

You don't have to do anything with the result, you just have to call the method in the same transactional context as the .find call.  Triggering the property will cause the EntityManager to load the field.  Then you can pass your internet object whereever and expect the brow property to be non-null.

Comment: i thought i should work, but it didn't can u check my latest post please.